# Unable to source PATH variable

Tags: path, android

I am able to `source` other variables except `PATH`

```
# cd /data/local
# mkdir env
# vi env/dev
<esc>i
PATH=/data/local/workspace/clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/bin:$PATH
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/data/local/workspace/clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/v1:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local/workspace/clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
<esc>:wq
# source env/dev
# echo $PATH                               
/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
# echo $CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH                 
/data/local/workspace/clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/v1:
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH                    
/data/local/workspace/clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/lib:
```

I am in rooted `Android` shell.

I am able to set `$PATH` in interactive mode in terminal

```
PATH=/data/local/workspace/clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/bin:$PATH
echo $PATH
/data/local/workspace/clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/bin:/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
```

and I am able to do

```
which clang++
/data/local/workspace/clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/clang++
```

but not able to run the executable present in the `PATH`!

```
# clang++
tmp-mksh: clang++: No such file or directory
# ./clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/clang++
tmp-mksh: ./clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/clang++: No such file or directory
```

Here is the hex dump of the `PATH` as requested in comments

```
printf '%s\n' "$PATH" | hexdump -C
00000000  2f 73 62 69 6e 3a 2f 76  65 6e 64 6f 72 2f 62 69  |/sbin:/vendor/bi|
00000010  6e 3a 2f 73 79 73 74 65  6d 2f 73 62 69 6e 3a 2f  |n:/system/sbin:/|
00000020  73 79 73 74 65 6d 2f 62  69 6e 3a 2f 73 79 73 74  |system/bin:/syst|
00000030  65 6d 2f 78 62 69 6e 0a                           |em/xbin.|
00000038
```

Comment: Does setting it interactively work? Does the file have the right contents (`cat env/dev`)?

Comment: yes, setting it interactively works and the file has right contents. I did `cat` and copy pasted `PATH` interactively to get it work!

Comment: Did you cut the line length in you post. It looks chopped off... Could you please fix that?

Comment: Also, please add the output of `printf '%s\n' "$PATH" | hexdump -C` or similar (use `od -c` if `hexdump` is not available) to the question (after sourcing the file).